# How can I export Excel or CVS file with Kendo UI Hybrid (Mobile application)?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I am doing an hybrid application with Kendo UI Hybrid and using Progress Telerik Platform AppBuilder to develop it, specifically for Android and iOS, I need to export the data from Kendo Grid. The functionality of Kendo Grid to export to xls file works well in a web project, but when is in an App this functionality makes it appear that it does nothing.

I tried:

- with the examples of Kendo UI for jQuery (applied to Mobile App)

  - [Overview of Excel Export](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/excel/introduction#overview-of-excel-export)
    (Even I include the JZip Requirements)
  - [Overview of File Saving](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/save-files/introduction#overview-of-file-saving)

As I mentioned before, that examples works well in browser, but not in a Mobile App. Am I doing something wrong?, Or how can I achieve it?
This is my Kendo Grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar:        ["excel"],
    excel:          {allPages: true},
    dataSource:     {
        data:    ReportDetail,
        type:    "json",
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    ID_Chasis:       { type: "string", width: "80px" },
                    NP_FullFrame:    { type: "string" },
                    NP_Cliente:      { type: "string" },
                    MODELO:          { type: "string" },
                    Descripcion:     { type: "string" },
                    Fecha_Producido: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    excelExport: function(e) {
        //Here I tried an example from the documentation
        var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < sheet.rows.length; i++) {
            sheet.rows[i].cells.reverse();
            for (var ci = 0; ci < sheet.rows[i].cells.length; ci++) {
                sheet.rows[i].cells[ci].hAlign = "right";
            }
        }
    },
    pageable:       {pageSize:    10,
    buttonCount: 1},
    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    detailInit:     detailInit,
    dataBound:      function() {},
    columns:        [{field: "ID_Chasis",     title: "ID", template: '<h6>#= ID_Chasis #</h6>'},
                     {field: "NP_FullFrame",    title: "Frame", template: '<h6>#= NP_FullFrame #</h6>'},
                     {field: "Fecha_Producido", title: "Fecha y hora", template: '<h6>#= kendo.toString(Fecha_Producido, "t") #<h6>'}]
});
```